# How to copy a Node.js applications current runtime state

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I would like to save the current state of a Node.js application including the current state of execution. I have had a look into the [Node.js VM Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) which looked promising however it doesn't save the current point of execution, only the current context. So when the code is executed again it will begin from line 1. Are there any Node.js functions that can assist with this or any lower level calls that can be made?

Essentially I would like to be able to run a script. Then at a random point in time, halt and save the execution state. Then later load this execution state and resume execution from the exact point that it was halted.

Comment: What is the higher level use case and what exactly is being executed?

Comment: The higher level use case is to create a mobile agent platform that can allow any JavaScript program to move from device to device resuming execution at the new node.

Comment: Node.js state is also dependant on environment, consider using Docker to completely isolate the Node.js application and ensure the state of the application can be consistently reproduced,

Comment: I don't think nodejs has any features that support this.  This would need to save the internal state of globals, closures, all module state, etc...   Plus some modules initialize their state based on the environment they are running in so this would not even be possible in some cases.  Imagine a module that opens a webSocket connection to an outside host when it is initialized or opens a local file or opens a local database - so this is not generically even possible without rerunning module initialization code.

Comment: You could build this feature into your own app where you ask your own app to save all of it's state to a set of files.  Then, when your app starts up, it checks for the existence of state files and, if present, it reinitalizes itself using that previous state.  But, you'd have to pretty much entirely code this yourself.

Comment: "*allow any program to move from device to device*" - there are special languages and runtimes allowed to do that. JS/node.js is not one of these.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to Java Aglet that you know of @Bergi ?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was worried about as I know there will be low level dependencies from each system architecture that would have to be essentially hotswapped which wouldn't be simple/practical. @jfriend00

Comment: So, it's not normally a big deal to just build an app that can save/restore it's own state.  In reality, state is usually not that complex.  Zillions of mobile apps already have that capability because the OS can send them a message that it's pushing them out of memory so they already have to be able to save/restore their own state.  It seems like you should just design that capability into your own app.  They don't attempt to save the entire runtime state.  They just save relevant app state and upon restart, they initialize normally and then read the previous app state.

Comment: @MattDavis I was thinking of [swarm](http://swarmframework.org/) or [unison](https://github.com/unisonweb/oldblog/blob/master/_posts/2015-06-02-distributed-evaluation.markdown) (although it appears the latter hasn't come far on that idea)